# Get values from different tables according to a given ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, left-join, union-all

I'm trying to get different names by checking different `StaffID` with `CASE` in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT StaffID,
       CASE WHEN StaffID IS NULL THEN 
          (SELECT C.Name FROM Customer as C, Ticket as T, TicketUpdate as TU
           WHERE TU.TicketID = 13 
           AND TU.TicketID = T.TicketID 
           AND T.CustomerID = C.CustomerID)

        WHEN StaffID IS NOT NULL THEN 
           (SELECT S.Name FROM Staff AS S, TicketUpdate as TU
           WHERE TU.TicketID = 13 
           AND TU.StaffID = S.StaffID offset)
        END
FROM ticketupdate
WHERE ticketid = 13;
```

If I'm not limiting the output to 1 I get an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> ```

But if I add `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query it takes only the first value for all StaffIDs

[image]

When in reality it looks like this:

[image]

As to my understanding it takes different IDs but won't take the associated name with it. I'm lost on this matter.

Comment: Please post the definition (e.g. `create table`) of the tables `customer`, `ticket`, `staff` and `ticketupdate`  (you should also learn how to use explicit `JOIN` syntax rather than implicit joins in the where clause)

Comment: Please, *always* provide your version of Postgres. In addition to what a_horse already requested, we need a proper explanation what you expect the query to return *exactly*.

Answer (score 1):

The query (as I understand it) is not trivial, it's easy to get lost here. What you have fails for multiple reasons, though.
Filling in with educated guesses for missing information, it could look like this:

```
SELECT staffid, s.name
FROM   ticketupdate tu
JOIN   staff        s USING (staffid)
WHERE  tu.ticketid = 13

UNION ALL
SELECT tu.staffid, c.name
FROM   ticketupdate  tu
LEFT   JOIN ticket   t USING (ticketid)
LEFT   JOIN customer c ON c.customerid = t.customerid
WHERE  tu.ticketid = 13
AND    tu.staffid IS NULL;
```

Assuming `staffid` is the primary key of `staff` and you have a foreign key constraint to it in `ticketupdate`, this retrieves *exactly one* `name` from `staff` per row where `staffid` is `NOT NULL`.

Else, retrieve any number of names from `customer` to produce 1-n rows in the result. `LEFT JOIN` guarantees at least one row as long as `ticketid` is found.